# NewRelic - monitoring cron tasks

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, newrelic

I have enabled 'background process monitoring' in my newrelic account. It monitors all the delayed_job processes and provides information on the most time consuming task, memory and cpu usage.

Is there a way we can monitor the cron tasks as well with newrelic?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://blog.newrelic.com/2012/05/30/using-new-relic-to-monitor-ruby-background-tasks/

If you don't want your background tasks to affect your Apdex:
https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/blocking-controller-instrumentation

Also the guys at New Relic are super helpful - don't be afraid to put in a support ticket!

Answer (score 0):

Another good resource on monitoring custom backgrounds jobs with New Relic is this doc:

https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/monitoring-ruby-background-processes-and-daemons#custom_background_jobs